# Why won't my UITableViewController footer height change?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-playground

I’m coding a mock messaging app in Swift Playgrounds, and to hold the messages I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom cell. I’m trying to add a “sticky” header and footer to the table, which will hold the navigation controls, and message entry and send button, respectively. I can’t seem to change the height of the header & footer though. I’ve tried using `tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)` & `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`, but that doesn’t work either.

Here’s what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var textMessages = [
        "Here's my very first message",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap",
        "some messaging"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Messages"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_1")
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        adddatextbruh()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 75))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 75))
        button.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        customView.addSubview(button)
        return customView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 75))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 75))
        button.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        customView.addSubview(button)
        return customView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textMessages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 1{
            cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            //cell.setupConstraints(side: 1)
            cell.bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
            return cell
        }else{
            cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            //cell.setupConstraints(side: 0)
            cell.bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
            return cell
        }
    }
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
    //        cell.textLabel?.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
    //        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    func adddatextbruh(){
        textMessages.append("hey whats up")
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [
            (NSIndexPath(row: textMessages.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: textMessages.count-1, section: 0), at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    }
}




class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let bubbleBackgroundView = UIView()
    var leadingAnchorConstant = CGFloat()

    func setupConstraints(side: Int){
        if side == 1{
            leadingAnchorConstant = frame.size.width - 176
        }else{
            leadingAnchorConstant = 32
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bubbleBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)

        addSubview(messageLabel)
        //        messageLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        messageLabel.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // lets set up some constraints for our label
        let constraints = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
                           messageLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

                           bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        //        messageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the follow function it isn't for the height

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        <#code#>
    }
```

and the next function is for the height.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return your_height
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I simply set `tableView.sectionFooterHeight = //the height` in viewDidLoad(). Not sure why heightForFooterInSection/headerInSection wasn’t working, but for me this is much cleaner anyways.

Comment: because you need to use this function for height:                                                    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }